# Is there any example of genetic mechanism of delayed onset toxic effects?

Tags: molecular-genetics, development, toxicology, epigenetics

We know that exposure to many toxic chemicals during embryonic development may show toxic effects later in life. It is called Developmental Origins of Health and Disease (DOHAD). Most of the mechanisms reported behind these kind of toxic effects are epigenetic. I could not find any genetic mechanism in the literature. Is there any example of genetic mechanisms behind DOHAD?

Comment: Are you asking for [mutagens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutagen) that are well known for its long term effects when exposed as a embryo?

Comment: I would tend to think that this question is off-topic here as it is a health question more than a biology question. [MedicalSciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit. See for example their [radioactivity tag](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radioactivity)

Comment: Mutagens might work but do you know of any specific mutagen, that can cause onset of toxicity only later in life even when the exposure happened during embryo phase?

Comment: Any mutagen would have health consequences later in life. I don't know of study on this question though and I can't really help you any further. You state `Mutagens might work` which makes me confused as to what other than exposure to mutagens would you be interested in.

Comment: @Remi.b this question is asking about a biological mechanism behind a medical condition. It is EXACTLY on topic here per the second of only three bullet points on [What topics can I ask about on here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I posted about this question [on meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/reminder-questions-about-biological-mechanisms-behind-medical-conditions-are-ex)